# Change Folder Ownership From Root To User

Tags: root, ownership

I think I may have seen this before but:

I want to change a folder from Root to owner (The User). 
I had done this before but forgot how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a terminal and enter `man chown` you wil; be presented with nifty documentation about how to change ownership of files and folders.

Basically, you want to issue the command

`sudo chown <new_owner> <path_to_file>`

Comment: Thank You I forgot the command so I will be writing this down for sure.